# How can I implement a .htaccess configuration in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

I have in my domain a .htaccess configuration that allows my app to work perfectly with the routes. It avoids the error when you refresh an angular 2 app can't resolve the routes.

My current config is this one

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I'm trying to implement the same configuration in my Firebase Hosting because I'm migrating my site, I don't know how to translate from .htaccess to Firebase Hosting configuration.

Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `.htaccess` in [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/), but you can configure it to rewrite, redirect, cache, etc.

Learn how to [customize hosting behavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites) here.

Your `.htaccess` would be translated to

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**/!(*.css|*.js|*.map|*.jpg|*.gif|*.png|*.php)",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly, now I have to test if all my .php files are allowed to write in the domain.

Comment: Is it possible to use the same principle to just enable all CORS in Friebase Hosing?