# Firebase serve webp when available and supported by browser - conditional rewrites

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

It is quite easy to create a rule in `.htaccess` that serves WebP images when the browser supports it (`RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp`) and the proper file exists on Your webserver.

For my next project, I'm considering firebase hosting and I'd like to serve WebP images.

Because [firebase doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46131976/965722) `.htaccess` I can't reuse rules I have.

Can I rewrite requests to png and jp(e)g files to go to webp files, of course, if that file exists and browser supports webp?

`.htaccess` file I use for reference looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/$1.webp -f
  RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=EXISTING:1,E=ADDVARY:1,L]

  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.(jpe?g|png)$" ADDVARY
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
      SetEnvIf REDIRECT_EXISTING 1 EXISTING=1
      SetEnvIf REDIRECT_ADDVARY 1 ADDVARY=1

      Header append "Vary" "Accept" env=ADDVARY

    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
```

Is adding picture element with additional source my only option or can this be done on firebase?

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 1921px)" srcset="src/images/very-large/bike.webp">
    <source type="image/png" media="(min-width: 1921px)" srcset="src/images/very-large/bike.png">
    <img src="src/images/bike-2003909.png" style="width: 100%;">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for browser detection in Firebase Hosting's `firebase.json` configuration file. The rewrites are much less advanced than those of your `.htaccess` example.